# Bootstrap form does not work properly - Symfony

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, symfony5

I have a problem with bootstrap (4.5.2) added to Symfony project(5.1.3).

I've added all links from starting-template to base.html.twig file:[image]

Everything from bootstrap works properly(for example NavBar) excluding forms.
It means, inputs does not have "bootstrap style" "out of the box". I am sure it was working in previous versions of Bootstrap/Symfony but not now.
Maybe I missed some command or now I need to set something but I don't know what.

Here is how it is looking right now: [image]

What I expect "out of the box": [image]

I know that if I'll add "form-control" class I'll achieve this but earlier it was working automatically.

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Greetings

Comment: From my experience you have to have at least the `form-control` class on the input elements in order to get the basic styling to work. If you remove that you will get the un-styled results you show in your picture.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a config in `config/packages/twig.yaml`

```
twig:
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

Comment: Thank you, Man!
I've missed exactly this line.